# How to add presets and Equalizer on audio in iOS?

Tags: ios, equalizer

I am working on an app which uses AVAudioPlayer to play a audio file. That's working fine, but now I want to add Equalizer presets.

Is there any library for presets in iOS?

Comment: i dnt know, the library present in ios. but "EZaudio have done". check the below link https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio

Comment: Could you please show your code? What did you try?